# How can I show rows with the value 'ALL' when a specific value is entered into a slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset that references projects, and the specific divisions each project is related to. Some projects are related to all divisions. The related divisions are in a single column, and comma separated per project as below.
I want the projects where division is 'All' to show regardless of what is entered into the Division slicer

| Project | Division |
| --- | --- |
| A | Sales |
| B | IT |
| C | Sales, Admin |
| D | All |

I have split the Division out using the comma delimiter into separate rows, and I have created a unique table for the Divisions to use as a DIM table which I join against the project table.

If a user was to select 'Sales' in the Division slicer, I would like to show all projects under Sales, but also any projects with 'All' as the division.

Is this possible? I have tried different bridging tables but have not been able to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table with the Projects and Division.
One table just with the Divisions (no relationship) -> use this one as the slicer source.

[image]

Then create a filter measure like this, for example:

```
Filter = 
var Sl = SELECTEDVALUE(Divisions[Division], "All")
var projectDiv = SELECTEDVALUE(Projects[Division])
RETURN IF(Sl = "All" || projectDiv = "All" || CONTAINSSTRING(projectDiv, Sl), 1, 0)
```

And in your table visual, use that as a filter (note I called my measure Filter, please choose a better name):

[image]

[image]

[image]